# Is it possible to use SQLite pattern matching on a result set?

Tags: android, sqlite, pattern-matching

Is there a way I can apply the `LIKE` clause to a result set in SQLite?  What I would like to accomplish is the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE value LIKE 
(
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN prefix IS NOT NULL THEN prefix || '?' 
        ELSE code END
    FROM MyOtherTable
)
```

Adding the `?` to the end of does not allow me to wildcard search by the prefix and the `LIKE` just ends up functioning like an `IN` clause.

Is there some way to achieve this, or alternatively a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: `%` is sqlite wildcard, not `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is that **`?`** is not a pattern matching character, rather that **`_`** is for pattern matching any single character and **`%`** is for pattern matching a sequence of characters.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression - The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

**However**, you would also encounter issues if myOtherTable has multiple rows.

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyOtherTable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (value TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyOtherTable (prefix TEXT, code TEXT);

INSERT INTO MyOtherTable VALUES 
    (null,'mycode'), 
    ('A','myothercode'),
    ('S',null)
;
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
 ('Something'), -- matched by S%
 ('A something'), -- matched by A%
 ('mycode is this'), -- never matched as characters after mycode
 ('Another'), -- matched by A%
 ('mycode') -- matched by mycode
;

-- Intermediate
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN prefix IS NOT NULL THEN prefix || '%' 
        ELSE code END
    FROM MyOtherTable
;

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE value LIKE 
(
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN prefix IS NOT NULL THEN prefix || '%' 
        ELSE code END
    FROM MyOtherTable
);
```

The final result would be :-

A single row

```
mycode
```

**That is only the first result of the subquery is considered**.

If **`(null,'mycode'),`** is removed or commented out then the result would be :-

Two rows that match the now first A% i.e.

```
A something
Another
```

Removing or commenting out the first two **`(null,'mycode'),`** and **`('A','myothercode'),`** results in the single row :-

```
Something
```

Comment: Bummer, thanks for the info. Looks like I'm going to have to restructure my query to work how I want it to.

Comment: @cptchloroplast although bad news in that regard, could you please tick the question as answered, if you believe that it answers the question.